# Getting query error in OOP php

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm just new using OOP php and I'm having a hard time to figure out how to query in database using class method. Here's my code and I've got an error which I dont know how to solve.

I declared the connection variable but I don't know why it's undefined

> Notice: Undefined variable: connection
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

db.php

```
class DbConnector {

   private $serverName;
   private $userName;
   private $password;
   private $dbName;
   private $connection;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->serverName = "localhost";
      $this->userName = "root";
      $this->password = "attl";
      $this->dbName = "oop";

      $this->connection = new mysqli($this->serverName, $this->userName, $this->password, $this->dbName);

      if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
          $this->connection = die("Connection failed: " . $this->connection->connect_error);
      } 
  }

  public function getConnection(){
      return $this->connection;
  }
}
```

index.php

```
include('../queries/db.php');

class Users{

  private $connection;

  public function __construct(){
      $con = new DbConnector();
      $connection = $con->getConnection();
  }
  public function getUsers(){
      $sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM login");

      while($getUsers = $sql->fetch_array()){
          echo $getUsers['username'];
      }
  }

}

$user = new Users();
return $user->getUsers();
```

Comment: It's very different on the link that tagged above @hanky panky

Comment: Original question said `I'm getting error Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\views\index.php on line 13` so imho the duplicate flag is spot on it can help you with the solution quickly

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: yes thanks for that, but it's very different since as looking for the link it's not a class OOP method. @HankyPanky

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\views\index.php on line 13 

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\views\index.php on line 13  . I don't know but the connection is declared . @MUNISHKUMAR

Comment: kindly Reopen and remove the duplicate tagged @HankyPanky ? thanks

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten done, but that doesn't really help here

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Is this question still open/unsolved?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's solved by my self. Sorry to many question.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Oh I see, glad to hear it. I was going to post my answer below if you still want me to and to mark it as solved.

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Actually, I did post my answer below just now, since I had it already written up beforehand and wrote it way before the other answer I saw now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to access a locally scoped variable rather than a class property

```
public function getUsers(){
  $sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM login"); // HERE

  while($getUsers = $sql->fetch_array()){
      echo $getUsers['username'];
  }
}
```

this can't find a variable called `$connection` in that scope, you need to access the object property using `$this`.

```
class Users {

  private $connection;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $con = new DbConnector();
      // Assign this to object propety declared above 
      $this->connection = $con->getConnection();
  }

  public function getUsers()
  {
      // now access the object property set in constructor.
      $sql = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM login");

      while($getUsers = $sql->fetch_array()){
          echo $getUsers['username'];
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: *Cheers* Andrew. As I told the OP earlier; I didn't see your answer posted here where I asked her if the question was still open so I took the time to test it and figure out where she went wrong, and was in the process of typing it all up. Your answer explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring the following as private:
`private $connection;`

and including it in your construct:

```
  public function __construct(){
      $con = new DbConnector();
      $connection = $con->getConnection();
```

You need to use `$this` for its property:

```
$this->connection = $con->getConnection();
```

Then changing:

```
$sql = $connection->query
```

to

```
$sql = $this->connection->query
```

in order to use the connection property.

Now, I have to admit that I am not an OOP expert and there may be another way to have solved this, yet this is what I took from it, which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Free -ii- I just reprogram the code and run it. If u see my other Question AGAIN.. haha its different from here. But the other question is more on Controller which I don't know how it works. I just want to learn MVC slowly.

Comment: TBH, I had already written this up before seeing the other answer. I'm not kicking for rep here *lol* just saying. @GeninaAnneGabuten I'm just glad that you found your full solution. You're welcome *cheers*